# How to insert into partitioned table based on parted column

Tags: kdb

I have to add some data from a few days ago to an on-disk partitioned table. It is just a little bit of data for a specific sym.

What is the most efficient way of inserting the data into the correct indexes based on date & time to ensure the parted attribute is satisfied?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing special to do other that upsert + sort + apply attribute.

- `upsert` https://code.kx.com/q/ref/upsert/
- `xasc` on disk https://code.kx.com/q/ref/asc/#sorting-data-on-disk
- `#` to apply the attribute https://code.kx.com/q/ref/set-attribute/

Roughly similar to:

```
hdb:`:/path/to/hdb
d:2023.01.01
t:tab


.Q.dd[hdb;(d;t;`)] upsert newData
`sym`time xasc .Q.dd[hdb;(d;t;`)]
.[.Q.dd[hdb;(d;t;`sym)];();`p#]
```